# How to SQL join two different tables (non-related)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Help as I need to join two different tables. Please see the details below.

Rates

```
ID RateName
1  Standard
2  Special
3  Custom
```

Dates

```
ID Date
1  10/01/2017
2  10/02/2017
3  10/03/2017
```

Expected Result

```
ID RateName Date
1  Standard 10/01/2017
1  Standard 10/02/2017
1  Standard 10/03/2017
2  Special  10/01/2017
2  Special  10/02/2017
2  Special  10/03/2017
3  Custom   10/01/2017
3  Custom   10/02/2017
3  Custom   10/03/2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `cross join`:

```
select r.*, d.*
from rates r cross join
     dates d
order by r.id, d.date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply select from two table without any join condition to get the desired result. That will apply cross join

```
select r.ID, r.RateName, d.Date
from rates r ,dates d
order by r.ID, d.date
```

Comment: **that IS a "cross join"** just expressed in old fashioned syntax, and that syntax not encouraged any longer. Use an explicit `cross join` so you know it isn't an accident.